Unity 2D sidescroller Raycast ground detection problem
I have a character with box collider 2d attached to it and 2 raycasts facing down to check if the character is grounded (if it collides with groundlayer it sets isGrounded= true). But there is a problem, Raycasts sometimes identify walls as ground (they share the same layer).
I have tried everything, but didnt help.

So, there must be some way to identify them as well, either put them on another layer, or, have some other method of identifying them...
